# How to assign a mathematical expression to an attribute in python?

Tags: python-2.7, constructor, functional-programming

I want to assign a mathematical expression (or a function) to an attribute in python. But so far I only know how to assign hard parameters like Int, Double or Boolean. In the code bellow is some kind of similarity for what I want.

```
class MyClass:

def __init__(self, mathExp):

    self.Expression=mathExp

def evalExp(self,param)
    return self.Expression(param)
```

What I want is mathExp to be something like "1+2x" and when I execute the function evalExp I can enter a parameter like 5 so that the return is something like 1+2*5=11.

Thanks for your help!,

Comment: this may help: http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: Thank you!, it was really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your input, which is a string, into something which can be handled by python. That is if you are not importing a library which can do this kind of stuff for you, like [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

If you want to do it yourself you need to build your mathematical language out of simpler expression, so that in the end after parsing your example input, you could have a list/tree/... like:

```
[1, add, [ 2, mul, 'x']]
```

Which then could be evaluated step by step. Safe to say, this is not the easiest task to take on.

### The genuine solution

If you used reverse polish notation, i.e. changing from "1+2x" to "1 2 x * +", this would be somewhat easier, as the list of tokens could look like:

```
[1, 2, x, mul, add]
```

And then you could go through it calculating as you read tokens:

- `1` – Push number onto a stack
- `2` – Push another number onto the stack
- `x` – Get an input, and push that onto the stack
- `mul` – Get two numbers from stack, multiply, and push back on stack. I.e. for `x=5`, push `2*5=10` back on stack
- `add` – Get two numbers from stack, i.e. `1, 10`, and add them, push back on stack

Now the input token list is empty, and the stack has one value `11`. Ready for the next calculation.

### The fake and unsafe solution

However, if you set aside safety and security issues, you could go down this path:

```
expression = "1 + 2*x"      # The '*' needs explicitly to be there
x = 5
result = eval(expression)
print result                # Will output '11'
```

In other words, you then search for the presence of letters/words, and ask using `raw_input` to set these, before sending the entire expression of to `eval`. However using `eval` opens up a lot of pitfalls as it can evaluate all code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer holroy!

I don't understand, when you say, get an input, you mean like using a parameter of a function?. I'm actually using the "fake and unsafe solution", but I want to get what you mean with 'unsafe'.